# ExpressJS body-parser is not working, it is empty in post request

Tags: typescript, express, body-parser

I created a server using `express.js`, `body-parser` with `typescript` like following.

`app.ts`

```
import express, { Application, Request, Response } from 'express';
import morgan from 'morgan';
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';
// import Router from './routes';
import cors from 'cors';

const app: Application = express();

app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(morgan('tiny'));
// app.use('/api', Router);
app.post('/test', (req: Request, res: Response) => {
    console.log("req.body => ", req.body)
    res.send(req.body)
})

export default app;
```

`index.ts`

```
import app from './app';
import * as dotenv from 'dotenv';
dotenv.config();

app.listen(process.env.PORT, () => {
  // tslint:disable-next-line: no-console
  console.log(`HTTP Server successfully started at port ${process.env.PORT}`);
});
```

`.env`

```
PORT=8080
```

`package.json`

```
...
"scripts": {
    "start": "node build/index.js",
    "build": "tsc",
    "dev": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development && nodemon",
    ...
},
"devDependencies": {
    "@types/cors": "^2.8.10",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.8",
    "@types/jest": "^29.5.3",
    "@types/morgan": "^1.9.1",
    "@types/node": "^14.17.7",
    "@types/supertest": "^2.0.12",
    "jest": "^26.6.3",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.15",
    "sequelize-cli": "^6.2.0",
    "supertest": "^6.3.3",
    "ts-jest": "^26.4.4",
    "ts-node": "^10.1.0",
    "tslint": "^6.1.3",
    "typescript": "^4.0.3"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
    "dotenv": "^10.0.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "morgan": "^1.10.0",
    ...
  },
...
}
```

I sent request using Postman.

```
// header
Content-Type: application/json

// endpoint
POST http://localhost:8080/test

// body
{
    "title": "Testing",
    "description": "I am testing server."
}
```

The backend console's result is

```
req.body => {}
```

It should be `req.body => { "title": "Testing", "description": "I am testing server." }`, but it is empty.
I tried to solve this problem for about 2 hours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated `app.ts` like this. It works.

```
import express, { Application, Request, Response } from 'express';
import morgan from 'morgan';
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';
// import Router from './routes';
import multer from 'multer';
import cors from 'cors';

const app: Application = express();
const upload = multer()

app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(upload.none()); 
app.use(morgan('tiny'));
// app.use('/api', Router);
app.post('/test', (req: Request, res: Response) => {
    console.log("req.body => ", req.body)
    res.send(req.body)
})

export default app;
```

I installed `multer`. It works with `form-data`.

Answer (score -1):

Express has it's own body `parser.json()` method. Instead of

```
bodyparser.josn()
```

Try using

```
express.json()
```

And make sure to send the data in postman selection the post method and use the raw section to dend the json object.

Comment: My code works in `x-www-form-urlencoded` mode, doesn't work in `form-data` mode. Also it doesn't work with `fetch` function in javascript.